# How to truncate then round a number in SQL Server 2008 R2

Tags: sql-server

Given these 2 examples, what is the correct syntax to round each example to the whole number. This must be a set operation as the decimal is from a column.

96.001 will be 96

80.01 will be 81

Thank you,
Stephen

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
;WITH T(C) AS
(
SELECT 96.001 
UNION ALL 
SELECT 80.01 
)

SELECT CEILING(CAST(C AS DECIMAL(18,2)))
FROM T
```

Answer (score 1):

You are looking for the `CEILING` and `FLOOR` functions.

Comment: Not quite. The question wasn't very clear, but '96.001' should be truncated to '96.00' and then rounded (up), which results in 96. '80.01' is truncated to '80.01' and then rounded (up), which results in 81.

Comment: That's why you want ceiling().  80.01 rounds to 80, not 81.  To get 81 from 80.01 you use ceiling().

Answer (score 0):

```
declare @myVar1 decimal(6,2)
declare @myVar2 decimal(6,2)
set @myvar1 = 96.001
set @myvar2 = 80.01

SELECT @myvar1, CAST(CEILING(@myVar1) as int), @myvar2, CEILING(@myVar2)
```

Result:

```
96.001   |   96   |   80.010   |   81
```